# .htaccess RewriteRule forbidden except folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpforbiddenhandler

I have this rule in **.htaccess**

```
# prevents files starting with dot to be viewed by browser
RewriteRule /\.|^\. - [F]
```

I need Forbidden all files with start dot, it's OK. But I need allow folder **.well-known**

How do you do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add another rule first, with nothing but the `[L]` flag, meaning "stop here if this rule matches":

```
# Match this path and do nothing
RewriteRule /\.well-known|^\.well-known - [L]
# prevents files starting with dot to be viewed by browser
RewriteRule /\.|^\. - [F]
```

Or you could qualify your existing rule with a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! /\.well-known|^\.well-known
RewriteRule /\.|^\. - [F]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead to allow that specific folder:

```
RewriteRule (?:^|/)\.(?!well-known(?:/.*)?$) - [F,NC]
```